# NStableView does not show my data

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, tableview

I have a tableView with an image and a textField but they are not showing the data. What could be missing?

I have tableColumn identifier set as MainCell...
I converted  obj-c from [here](https://github.com/lucasderraugh/AppleProg-Cocoa-Tutorials/blob/master/Lesson%2051/Lesson%2051/AppDelegate.m) to swift.

Any suggestions?

```
import Cocoa

class viewTime: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

var tableContents:NSMutableArray = []

@IBOutlet var tableView: NSTableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let path: NSString = "/Library/Application Support/Apple/iChat Icons/Flags"
    let fileManager:FileManager = FileManager.default
    let directoryEnum:FileManager.DirectoryEnumerator = fileManager.enumerator(atPath: path as String)!

        while let file = directoryEnum.nextObject() as? NSString{
            let filePath:NSString = path.appendingFormat("/%@", file)
            let obj:NSDictionary = ["image": NSImage(byReferencingFile:filePath as String), "name": file.deletingPathExtension]
            print("obj:\(obj)")
            tableContents.add(obj)
        }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return tableContents.count
}


private func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView! {
    let cellView = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "MainCell", owner: self) as! NSTableCellView

    let flag:NSDictionary = tableContents[row] as! NSDictionary
    let identifier:NSString = tableColumn!.identifier as NSString

    if (identifier == "MainCell") {

        cellView.textField?.stringValue = flag["name"] as! String
        cellView.imageView!.image = flag["image"] as? NSImage
        return cellView
    }
    return nil
}
```

}

Comment: Put in some breakpoints to check if the data and cells are all valid.

Comment: at print("obj:\(obj)") I get all data in the console. Also tableView outlet is connected

Comment: did you make sure to connect your `MainCell` outlets (`textField` and `imageView`)?

Comment: Did you also check the return value of `viewForTableColumn` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating Objective-C to Swift literally is always a bad idea.

- First of all make sure that both `datasource` and `delegate` of the table view are connected to the view controller in Interface Builder.
- Make sure also that the Identifier of the `NSTableCellView` is `MainCell`
- **Most important change**: Create a custom struct, it makes things so much easier.

  ```
  struct Asset {
    var name : String
    var image : NSImage
  }
  ```
- Declare the data source array as Swift Array of the struct type.

  ```
   var tableContents = [Asset]()
  ```
- This is `viewDidLoad` in real Swift code. Don't annotate types unless the compiler tells you to do.

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath:"/Library/Application Support/Apple/iChat Icons/Flags")
    let enumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: [], options: .skipsHiddenFiles, errorHandler: nil)!

    for case let fileURL as URL in enumerator {
      let asset = Asset(name: fileURL.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent, image: NSImage(contentsOf:fileURL)!)
      tableContents.append(asset)
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
  ```
- `numberOfRows` is OK.
- `tableView:viewForColumn:Row` can be simplified as there is only one identifier and one column.

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    let cellView = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "MainCell", owner: self) as! NSTableCellView

    let asset = tableContents[row]

    cellView.textField!.stringValue = asset.name
    cellView.imageView!.image = asset.image
    return cellView
  }
  ```

Comment: very thorough.Thanks!